# How to perform K-Fold Cross Validation in a Neural Network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, cross-validation

I'm developing a CNN for a binary image classification problem (Cats/Dogs).
My goal is to use K-Fold CV (in this case I'd apply 5 folds) to find the best parameters (batch size, epochs).

so far my code is this

```
# Defining the Loss
loss = binary_crossentropy

# Creating the grid of parameters
batches = [32, 64, 128, 256]
epochs = [20, 30, 40, 50]
params_grid = dict(batch_size = batches, epochs = epochs)

# Creating the model
def model_cnn_three_layer(optimizer='adam'):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding = "same", use_bias=False, input_shape = (64, 64, 1), activation = 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding = "same", use_bias=False, activation = 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding = "same", use_bias=False, activation = 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding = "same", use_bias=False, activation = 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, use_bias=False, activation = 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation = 'softmax')
    ])

    # Compiling the model
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.summary()

    return model

# Create the sklearn CV model for the network

model_cnn_three_layer_CV = KerasClassifier(build_fn=model_cnn_three_layer, verbose=1)

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model_cnn_three_layer_CV, 
                    param_grid=params_grid,
                    cv=5)

grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Print results
print(f'Best Accuracy for {grid_result.best_score_:.4} using {grid_result.best_params_}')
means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print(f'mean={mean:.4}, std={stdev:.4} using {param}')
```

Is this approach correct?

If I wanted to compute the CV 'manually' (not using sklearn) how would I change the code?
I found an answer to a similar question that does something like this

```
# parameters
epochs = 20
batch_size = 64

# Defining callback(s)
early_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=3)

# Defining plots
legend_size = 14

# Define the K-fold Cross Validator
num_folds = 5
kfold = KFold(n_splits=num_folds, shuffle=True)

loss_cnn_three_layer = []
acc_cnn_three_layer = []

fold_no = 1
for train, test in kfold.split(X, y):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding = "same", use_bias=False, input_shape = (64, 64, 1), activation = 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding = "same", use_bias=False, activation = 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding = "same", use_bias=False, activation = 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding = "same", use_bias=False, activation = 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, use_bias=False, activation = 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation = 'softmax')
    ])

    # compiling the model
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=loss, metrics=['accuracy'])

    net_name = "CNN_three_layers_batch_and_dropout"

    model.summary()

    # log dir for saving TensorBoard logs
    logdir = os.path.join("CNN_nets", net_name)

    # callback to run TensorBoard
    tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir, histogram_freq=1)
    callbacks = [tensorboard_callback, early_callback]

    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
                        batch_size=batch_size, callbacks=callbacks, verbose=1)

    scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
    print(
        f'Score for fold {fold_no}: {model.metrics_names[0]} of {scores[0]}; {model.metrics_names[1]} of {scores[1] * 100}%')
    acc_cnn_three_layer.append(scores[1] * 100)
    loss_cnn_three_layer.append(scores[0])

    # Increase fold number
    fold_no = fold_no + 1

# == Provide average scores ==
print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
print('Score per fold')
for i in range(0, len(loss_cnn_three_layer)):
    print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print(f'> Fold {i + 1} - Loss: {loss_cnn_three_layer[i]} - Accuracy: {acc_cnn_two_layer[i]}%')
print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
print('Average scores for all folds:')
print(f'> Accuracy: {np.mean(acc_cnn_three_layer)} (+- {np.std(acc_cnn_three_layer)})')
print(f'> Loss: {np.mean(loss_cnn_three_layer)}')
print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
```

But I'm not convinced by this approach, because it simply runs the model 5 times on the same data and not on different splits of the training data. How would this be changed to effectively run a CV on split portions of the train data and then evaluate on the test data? Moreover, how would I loop this last network over the values of the parameters of the grid?

EDIT: THIS IS THE FULL CODE SO FAR THAT I'M APPLYING

```
y = pickle.load(open('y.pickle','rb'))
pets_classes = ['Cats','Dogs']

X = pickle.load(open('X.pickle','rb'))


# Conversion of X (images) to grayscale
X = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(X)

# rescale in [0,1]
X = tf.cast(X, tf.float32) / 255.0

# Defining Loss, Optimizer, and lists of iterable Hyperparameters
# Defining the loss
loss = binary_crossentropy

# Defining the optimizer
optimizer = Adam()

# batches and epochs lists
batches = [32, 64, 128, 256]
epochs = [20, 30, 40, 50]

# Defining 5-fold cross validation
splits = 5
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True)
splitted_folds = kfold.split(X, y)
cvscores = []

# one-hot encoding of y
depth = 1
y = tf.reshape(tf.one_hot(y, depth), shape = [x_size, depth])


# CREATING THE MODEL WITH CROSS VALIDATION

loss_cnn_three_layer = []
acc_cnn_three_layer = []

# create the first loop for batches and epochs
for k, l in [(i, j) for j in epochs for i in batches]:   
# second loop for training the model on each split
    for train, test in splitted_folds:
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[train], X[test], y[train], y[test]

        model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding = "same", use_bias=False, input_shape = (64, 64, 1), activation = 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding = "same", use_bias=False, activation = 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding = "same", use_bias=False, activation = 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding = "same", use_bias=False, activation = 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, use_bias=False, activation = 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')
        ])
    
        # compiling the model
        model.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=['accuracy'])

        net_name = "CNN_three_layers_batch_and_dropout"

        model.summary()


        # log dir for saving TensorBoard logs
        logdir = os.path.join("CNN_nets", net_name)

        # callback to run TensorBoard
        tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir, histogram_freq = 1)
        callbacks = [tensorboard_callback, early_callback]
        
        # fitting the network
        history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = l,
                            batch_size = k, callbacks = callbacks, verbose = 1)

        # evaluating the performance
        scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
        
        # printing accuracy and loss
        print(f'Score per batch {k} and epochs {l}: {model.metrics_names[0]} of {scores[0]}; {model.metrics_names[1]} of {scores[1]*100}%')
        acc_cnn_three_layer.append(scores[1] * 100)
        loss_cnn_three_layer.append(scores[0])
        cvscores.append(scores)
```

Now the problem is that it runs the Cross Validation only on the first tuple (or combination) of batch/epoch (32,20) and then it automatically stops as if the process was finished.
If I try tu rerun the network this message appears

```
C:\Users\loren\anaconda3\envs\global_packs\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:3440: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
  return _methods._mean(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
C:\Users\loren\anaconda3\envs\global_packs\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:189: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
C:\Users\loren\anaconda3\envs\global_packs\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:262: RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice
  ret = _var(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, ddof=ddof,
C:\Users\loren\anaconda3\envs\global_packs\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:222: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  arrmean = um.true_divide(arrmean, div, out=arrmean, casting='unsafe',
C:\Users\loren\anaconda3\envs\global_packs\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:254: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
```

What does this mean? How can I solve it?

Comment: You never applied the kfold indices to your dataset. It should be similar to: `x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test= X[train], X{test], y[train], y[test]` then use those as input for your model. You also just use `enumerate()` instead of keeping track of `fold_no`.

Comment: Are you referring to the first or second method? And those `X[train], X{test], y[train], y[test]` have to be used as inputs in `grid.fit(X_train, y_train)` (if using the first method) or `kfold.split(X,y)`, and `model.fit` (if using the second one)?

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold as kfold

x = # features
y = # labels

batches = [32, 64, 128, 256]
epochs = [20, 30, 40, 50]

splits = 5
kf = kfold(splits, shuffle=True)
indices = kf.split(x, y)
loss_cnn_three_layer = []
acc_cnn_three_layer = []
preds = []
for train, test in indices:
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = x[train], x[test], y[train], y[test]

    # do model stuff

    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, shuffle=True, epochs=10, verbose=1)
    prediction = model.predict(x_test)
    loss_cnn_three_layer.append(history.history["loss"])
    acc_cnn_three_layer.append(history.history["accuracy"])
    preds.append(prediction)
```

Edit to include iterable of parameters:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold as kfold

x = # features
y = # labels

splits = 5
kf = kfold(splits, shuffle=True)
indices = kf.split(x, y)
loss_cnn_three_layer = []
acc_cnn_three_layer = []
preds = []
for batch, epochs in zip(batches, epochs):
    for train, test in indices:
        x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = x[train], x[test], y[train], y[test]

        # do model stuff
        
        history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, shuffle=True, batch_size=batch epochs=epochs, verbose=1)
        prediction = model.predict(x_test)
        loss_cnn_three_layer.append(history.history["loss"])
        acc_cnn_three_layer.append(history.history["accuracy"])
        preds.append(prediction)
```

If you want to iterate different batches and epochs based on the kfold instead, just swap the two `for` placements, but leave everything else within.

If you want to have the dictionary, do something like this:

```
for i, j in zip([*params_grid.values()]):  # assuming batch and epoch lists have the same length
    # where i is batch, and j is epochs
    # do stuff
```

If you wanted to train the model based on the number of epochs per batch size (or vice versa*), do something like this:

```
for k, l in [(i, j) for j in epochs for i in batches]:  # swap batches and epochs for vice versa*
    # where k is batch, and l is epochs
    # do stuff
```

Comment: Ok, got it. But then how would I iterate it through the parameters of my grid? Should I add an additional for loop before the k-fold loop with `for key, value in params_grid.items()`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I'm asking if it's possible, instead of setting a precise number of epochs and batch size for the model, can I perform the CV that you're proposing using the grid of parameters of my first method in order to find the best number for epochs and batch? I mean `batches = [32, 64, 128, 256]
epochs = [20, 30, 40, 50]
params_grid = dict(batch_size = batches, epochs = epochs)
`

Comment: Check the updated answer, no need to put them in a dictionary, since you already have them as lists, but if you really just have to put them in a dictionary, you'd end up retrieving them into lists anyway. So it's better to just remove the dictionary unless you really need it.

Comment: One last question. If I want to retrieve the validation accuracy and loss instead of the prediction, I can substitute `model.predict(x_test)` with `model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)` and store them in a different list, for example, `cvscores = []` rather than `preds = []`, right?

Comment: If I run the example in the edit it just runs the 5-fold cv just on the first values of the lists (batch = 32 and epochs = 20) and then it stops. If I substitute the for loop for batch and epochs with `for k, l in [[(i, j) for j in epochs] for i in batches]` it return the error `too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: Yes to the first question. I corrected the answer to the second question. I accidentally made a nested list of tuples instead of a list of tuples.

Comment: Also please update your question with your code.

Comment: Check the answer I posted

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following solution

```
loss_cnn_three_layer = []
acc_cnn_three_layer = []

# create the first loop for batches and epochs
for batch, epoch in zip(batches, epochs):   
# second loop for training the model on each split
    for train, test in indices:
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[train], X[test], y[train], y[test]

        # model = tf.keras.Sequential([ ... ])
    
        # compiling the model
        model.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=['accuracy'])

        net_name = "CNN_three_layers_batch_and_dropout"

        model.summary()


        # log dir for saving TensorBoard logs
        logdir = os.path.join("CNN_nets", net_name)

        # callback to run TensorBoard
        tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir, histogram_freq = 1)
        callbacks = [tensorboard_callback, early_callback]
        
        # fitting the network
        history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = epoch,
                            batch_size = batch, callbacks = callbacks, verbose = 1)

        # evaluating the performance
        scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
        
        # printing accuracy and loss
        print(f'Score per batch {batch} and epochs {epoch}: {model.metrics_names[0]} of {scores[0]}; {model.metrics_names[1]} of {scores[1]*100}%')
        acc_cnn_three_layer.append(scores[1] * 100)
        loss_cnn_three_layer.append(scores[0])
```

However by doing this it runs the model and the Cross Validation only on the first combination of batches and epochs (32, 20) and then it stops.

Comment: Is this in a loop? The code that's shown will loop through all the tuples in `zip(batches, epochs)`.

Comment: As a reference: `a = [1, 2, 3]; b = [4, 5, 6]; for i, j in zip(a, b): print(i + j)` outputs `5 7 9`. If you have the code structured correctly, it should go through the entire zipped lists unless something breaks the loop.

Comment: Yes but I don't know why it stops after the first tuple. In my case I'd like to obtain outputs `5, 6, 7 ... 9` (that is, `1+4, 1+5, 1+6 ... 3+6` , which is every element in the first list summed with each of the second). But it stops after the first tuple is computed. It doesn't show error, it just stops like the process is finished. Am I doing something wrong with the code, maybe the indentation? I tried with `for k, l in [(i, j) for j in epochs for i in batches]` but it doesn't change

Comment: Show your full code, or minimally reproducible code, not just a section, so it can be replicated.

Comment: check the comment I posted with the full code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Full code so far

```
y = pickle.load(open('y.pickle','rb'))
pets_classes = ['Cats','Dogs']

X = pickle.load(open('X.pickle','rb'))


# Conversion of X (images) to grayscale
X = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(X)

# rescale in [0,1]
X = tf.cast(X, tf.float32) / 255.0

# Defining Loss, Optimizer, and lists of iterable Hyperparameters
# Defining the loss
loss = binary_crossentropy

# Defining the optimizer
optimizer = Adam()

# batches and epochs lists
batches = [32, 64, 128, 256]
epochs = [20, 30, 40, 50]

# Defining 5-fold cross validation
splits = 5
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True)
splitted_folds = kfold.split(X, y)
cvscores = []

# one-hot encoding of y
depth = 1
y = tf.reshape(tf.one_hot(y, depth), shape = [x_size, depth])


# CREATING THE MODEL WITH CROSS VALIDATION

loss_cnn_three_layer = []
acc_cnn_three_layer = []

# create the first loop for batches and epochs
for k, l in [(i, j) for j in epochs for i in batches]:   
# second loop for training the model on each split
    for train, test in splitted_folds:
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[train], X[test], y[train], y[test]

        model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding = "same", use_bias=False, input_shape = (64, 64, 1), activation = 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding = "same", use_bias=False, activation = 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding = "same", use_bias=False, activation = 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding = "same", use_bias=False, activation = 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, use_bias=False, activation = 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')
        ])
    
        # compiling the model
        model.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=['accuracy'])

        net_name = "CNN_three_layers_batch_and_dropout"

        model.summary()


        # log dir for saving TensorBoard logs
        logdir = os.path.join("CNN_nets", net_name)

        # callback to run TensorBoard
        tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir, histogram_freq = 1)
        callbacks = [tensorboard_callback, early_callback]
        
        # fitting the network
        history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = l,
                            batch_size = k, callbacks = callbacks, verbose = 1)

        # evaluating the performance
        scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
        
        # printing accuracy and loss
        print(f'Score per batch {k} and epochs {l}: {model.metrics_names[0]} of {scores[0]}; {model.metrics_names[1]} of {scores[1]*100}%')
        acc_cnn_three_layer.append(scores[1] * 100)
        loss_cnn_three_layer.append(scores[0])
        cvscores.append(scores)
```

Comment: I just used that code (except lowered epochs to `[2, 3, 4, 5]` and removed tensorboard stuff) with my own data and it's going through all the batch sizes per epoch, then increasing epoch length.

Comment: Also, please don't add answers as comments. Just edit your question.

Comment: The code should go through each batch size 5 times for the training and validation part and then proceed to the next epoch size, right? Because in my case it keeps stopping after the first combination of batch/epoch.  It seems impossible because apparently I'm not seeing anything wrong with the model and the loops

Comment: Are you running out of memory?